# Oracle XE data limit reached - how to reduce tablespace size?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, resize, tablespace, data-files

I have an Oracle XE database with several tablespaces. One of these is used to store image data, and this tablespace has grown to a huge size. We decided that we didn't need to the images any more so deleted them all.

This has freed up a lot of space but the tablespace size is still huge. How can I reduce it back to the size of the data that's actually in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a full database export, drop the tablespace, create a new tablespace with a smaller size and import back into it

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this is the approach I used in the end. It was a lot simpler than having to defragment and resize the tablespace.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky, you would find **DATAFILE RESIZE** as the most common answer. However, you need to take care of few things as mentioned by [Jonathan Lewis](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/02/06/shrink-tablespace/) to avoid `ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value` while resizing the datafile.

You need to first find the **free space** of the **tablespace** to make sure how much you could **reclaim**.

The following script by [Tim Hall](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=monitoring&file=ts_free_space.sql) is handy:

```
SET PAGESIZE 140
COLUMN used_pct FORMAT A11

SELECT tablespace_name,
       size_mb,
       free_mb,
       max_size_mb,
       max_free_mb,
       TRUNC((max_free_mb/max_size_mb) * 100) AS free_pct,
       RPAD(' '|| RPAD('X',ROUND((max_size_mb-max_free_mb)/max_size_mb*10,0), 'X'),11,'-') AS used_pct
FROM   (
        SELECT a.tablespace_name,
               b.size_mb,
               a.free_mb,
               b.max_size_mb,
               a.free_mb + (b.max_size_mb - b.size_mb) AS max_free_mb
        FROM   (SELECT tablespace_name,
                       TRUNC(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024) AS free_mb
                FROM   dba_free_space
                GROUP BY tablespace_name) a,
               (SELECT tablespace_name,
                       TRUNC(SUM(bytes)/1024/1024) AS size_mb,
                       TRUNC(SUM(GREATEST(bytes,maxbytes))/1024/1024) AS max_size_mb
                FROM   dba_data_files
                GROUP BY tablespace_name) b
        WHERE  a.tablespace_name = b.tablespace_name
       )
ORDER BY tablespace_name;
```

All that remains now is to resize the data files.

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/directory/datafile.dbf' RESIZE value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - so Oracle won't allow you to resize a tablespace too small? Are there any other risks associated with resizing tablespaces?

Comment: Go through the two links I gave, it explains the pros and cons.